# python: need to close file from mkstemp if I use fdopen?

Tags: python, file, file-io, operating-system

Which of the following is more correct?

```
fi, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
f = os.fdopen(fi, "w")
f.write(res)
f.close()
os.close(fi)
```

or:

```
fi, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
f = os.fdopen(fi, "w")
f.write(res)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check `f.fileno()`, it should be the same as `fi`.  You should only ever close that file descriptor once, so the second is correct.

On Unix, the first causes an error:

```
>>> f.close()
>>> os.close(fi)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: gotcha. a bit confusing: open twice, close once. but i get the idea

Comment: `os.fdopen()` does not necessarily open the file descriptor, it just returns an open file object for the file desciptor.  If the file descriptor is already open it will not open it again.

Comment: @Claudiu: It's because the OS makes a difference between file *descriptors* (which are OS-level objects), and file *streams* (which are libc-level objects). `fopen` (`open` in Python) opens a descriptor, then opens a stream using this descriptor. `fdopen` opens a new stream using an existing descriptor. `fclose` (`file.close` in Python) closes a stream and its underlying descriptor.

Answer (score 3):

If on a sufficiently recent Python, you can golf this down to:

```
with os.fdopen(tempfile.mkstemp()[0]) as f:
    f.write(res)
```

Comment: hehe nice, but i need the path in this case

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the follow-up on the most recent answers, if you need the path:

```
f_handle, f_path = tempfile.mkstemp()
with os.fdopen(f_handle, 'w') as f:
    f.write(res)

try:
    # Use path somehow
    some_function(f_path)

finally:
    # Clean up
    os.unlink(f_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
fi, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
f = os.fdopen(fi, "w")
try:
  f.write(res)
finally:
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to write in the last example you'd need:

```
with os.fdopen(tempfile.mkstemp()[0], 'w') as f:
     f.write(res)
```